# Can an adjusted estimate ever be further away from the true value than the unadjusted estimate?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, predictor

Suppose we generate a Gaussian random variable

y = a + bx1 + cx2 + e

and then run two regressions:

1) y on x1
2) y on x1 and x2

Is it ever possible for the second regression to provide worse estimates for x1 than the first regression? Why does this happen?

Comment: Your question appears vacuous: these regressions estimate $y$, not $x_1$.  Did you mean to write "$y$" instead of "$x_1$" or did you intend to refer to the *coefficient* of $x_1$?

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible.  Here is some R code simulating $y=16+40x_1+2x_2+\epsilon$

```
> set.seed(2)
> x1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
> x2 <- c(3,1,3,1)
> epsilon <- rnorm(4,0,5) 
> print(epsilon)
[1] -4.4845727  0.9242459  7.9392267 -5.6518784
> y <- 16 + 40*x1 + 2*x2 + epsilon
> lm(y ~ x1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1  
      20.80        39.55  

> lm(y ~ x1 + x2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
      6.474       41.462        4.777
```

The fit without $x_2$ gives an estimate for the coefficient of $x_1$ which is closer to the true value of $40$ than the fit with $x_2$

This is a small dataset, the coefficient of $x_2$ is small while the error term is relatively large, and with this seed there is an accidental relationship between $x_1$, $x_2$ and $\epsilon$ which means that the presence of $x_2$ in the regression is not helpful even if it appears to increase $R^2$